# fullpage.js can't move to next section on touch device

Tags: touch, fullpage.js

I've set up a website using fullpage.js.
I have now problems on touch-devices: When autoScrolling is enabled I often can't swipe to an other section. It's like your already on the bottom of the page.
I have this issue on all touch-devices I've tried (Ipad & Iphone with Chrome and Safari, Android with Chrome). On a desktop computer i don't have this problem.

Visit www.airport-signage.com to see the issue.

My settings for fullpage.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['home', 'approach', 'work', 'services', 'company', 'team', 'contact'],
            menu: '#menu',
            'autoScrolling': true,
            'controlArrows': true,
            'slidesNavigation': false,
            'verticalCentered': false,
            'touchSensitivity': 5,
            'css3': true,
            'fixedElements': '#fixedHeader',
            'scrollOverflow': true,
            'normalScrollElements': '#map_canvas',
            'sectionsColor': ['#3df945', '#000', '#fff', '#3df945', '#000', '#fff', '#3df945'],
            'onLeave': function(){
                stuff
            },

        });
    });
```

What could the problem be? How can I fix it?

Comment: I can scroll perfectly from my iPhone 5. (which means it works as well in any other Apple device). The only problem I found was with section 3 trying to go down. It seems there's an element between section 3 and section 4, some grey div. That might be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

removing 
    'normalScrollElements': #map_canvas', 
helped me to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if the original poster ever figured out what was up.

I recently started using fullPage.js and it's not working as intended on mobile Chrome after inserting anchors for better navigation.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. [The demo site](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) works as expected.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap as well but can't track down the conflict. I'll post my old code when I get a chance soon.

Comment: @Alvaro Here's a link to my current staging which I am having issues with: [link](http://admin.minus7.media/)

As I mentioned before, it doesn't run well on my mobile Chrome using a Galaxy S6. It runs fine on my friend's iPhone and desktop works fine too.

Without the anchors, the page runs smoothly on my S6, but I want to be able to search back to the top of the page whenever the brand image is clicked at the top (which is enabled right now).